# Ajuda para - Otimizar MySQL

Tags: mysql, servidor

Estou com problemas para otimizar meu MySQL do VPS que uso.

Tenho um plano na RamNode com as seguintes specs:

- Intel® Xeon® CPU E3-1240 V2 @ 3.40GHz (4 Cores)
- 4GB de Ram
- 135 GB SSD Raid 10

Estou com problemas de lentidão em uma das aplicações que eu tenho hospedada, as vezes dá até erro `max user connections`.

Segue abaixo o teste realizado no MySQLTunner:

> MySQLTuner 1.3.0 - Major Hayden
>
> Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
>
> Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
>
> [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.42-cll
>
> [OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
>
> -------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
>
> [--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
>
> [--] Data in MyISAM tables: 136M (Tables: 300)
>
> [--] Data in InnoDB tables: 44M (Tables: 202)
>
> [--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
>
> [!!] Total fragmented tables: 220
>
> -------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
>
> [OK] All database users have passwords assigned
>
> -------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
>
> [--] Up for: 1d 20h 25m 13s (3M q [23.681 qps], 251K conn, TX: 9B, RX: 605M)
>
> [--] Reads / Writes: 57% / 43%
>
> [--] Total buffers: 528.0M global + 3.6M per thread (400 max threads)
>
> [OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.9G (48% of installed RAM)
>
> [OK] Slow queries: 0% (17/3M)
>
> [OK] Highest usage of available connections: 11% (47/400)
>
> [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 256.0M/23.3M
>
> [OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (49M cached / 5K reads)
>
> [OK] Query cache efficiency: 76.0% (1M cached / 2M selects)
>
> [!!] Query cache prunes per day: 7322
>
> [!!] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 69% (144K temp sorts / 208K sorts)
>
> [!!] Joins performed without indexes: 21719
>
> [OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (4K on disk / 574K total)
>
> [OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (47 created / 251K connections)
>
> [OK] Table cache hit rate: 87% (1K open / 1K opened)
>
> [OK] Open file limit used: 6% (1K/15K)
>
> [OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (1M immediate / 1M locks)
>
> [OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/44.1M
>
> [OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
>
> -------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
>
> General recommendations:
>
> Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
>
> Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
>
> Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
>
> Variables to adjust:
>
> query_cache_size (> 64M)
>
> sort_buffer_size (> 2M)
>
> read_rnd_buffer_size (> 236K)
>
> join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)

Segue meu My.CNF

```
[mysqld]

max_connections = 400

max_user_connections=40

key_buffer_size = 256M

myisam_sort_buffer_size = 16M

read_buffer_size = 1M

table_open_cache = 2048

thread_cache_size = 128

wait_timeout = 20

connect_timeout = 10

tmp_table_size = 128M

max_heap_table_size = 64M

max_allowed_packet=268435456

net_buffer_length = 5500

max_connect_errors = 10

concurrent_insert = 2

read_rnd_buffer_size = 242144

bulk_insert_buffer_size = 2M

query_cache_limit = 2M

query_cache_size = 64M

query_cache_type = 1

query_prealloc_size = 87382

query_alloc_block_size = 21845

transaction_alloc_block_size = 2730

transaction_prealloc_size = 1364

max_write_lock_count = 2

log-error

external-locking=FALSE

open_files_limit=15000



default-storage-engine=MyISAM

innodb_file_per_table=1

[mysqld_safe]



[mysqldump]

quick

max_allowed_packet = 8M



[isamchk]

key_buffer = 128M

sort_buffer = 128M

read_buffer = 64M

write_buffer = 64M



[myisamchk]

key_buffer = 128M

sort_buffer = 128M

read_buffer = 64M

write_buffer = 64M



#### Per connection configuration ####

sort_buffer_size = 2M

join_buffer_size = 2M

thread_stack = 192K

log-slow-queries
```

Se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço :)

Comment: O erro não pode estar em sua aplicação? Siga a sessão de recomendações no arquivo que você postou, porém acredito que o problema está nas aplicações.

Comment: Exato, também acho que o problema é na aplicação. Rode um `show full processlist`enquanto estiver lento e tente identificar uma consulta que esteja demorando muito. Use também o `explain`do MySQL para entender as conultas e otimizá-las. Se achar alguma suspeita adicione à pergunta ou faça outra mais específica.

Answer (score 2):

Problema resolvido com a pergunta bo Stackoverflow em inglês

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350856/how-to-optimize-mysql-centos/29351254?noredirect=1#comment46894424_29351254

O problema era má configuração do Arquivo My.cnf e tbm conversão das tabelas pra InnoDB